# Global error handler with Spring @ControllerAdvice doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, error-handling, spring-3

Anyone know why the following code failed to capture the exception?

```
package org.rythmengine.spring.web.servlet.view;

import org.rythmengine.RythmEngine;
import org.rythmengine.exception.RythmException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@ControllerAdvice
public class RythmExceptionHandler {

    RythmEngine engine;

    @Autowired
    public RythmExceptionHandler(RythmConfigurer conf) {
        this.engine = conf.getRythmEngine();
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = RythmException.class)
    public ModelAndView defaultErrorHandler(RythmException e) throws Exception {
        if (engine.mode().isProd()) {
            throw e;
        }
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("exception", e);
        mav.setViewName("errors/500.html");
        return mav;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your configuration.

Comment: Which exception? Where's the stack trace? Where's the code throwing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. It needs to add one line in the configuration file:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.rythmengine.spring.web.servlet.view"/>
```

And also need to add `@EnableWebMvc` annotation in additional to the `@ControllerAdvice` annotation.

However I can't force user to add the component in their configuration, or I want to make it transparent to user. Thus the solution become the following code:

```
    if (engine.isDevMode()) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        ctx.scan("org.rythmengine.spring.web.servlet.view");
    }
```

This is not the end so far. It successfully capture the Exception in user's controller code, but not the exception in the view rendering process. I am looking for a way to add `HandlerInterceptor` so that it can handle error in `DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletion(...)`

**Updates**

The above code proved not working. The final solution is adding the following annotation to an arbitrary class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("org.rythmengine.spring.web.servlet.view")
```

And yes, now I don't need user to add the `<context:component-scan ...>` into their xml configuration file.

With regarding to render time exception handling, I cache the exception internally in the `RythmView` class in case there are error (usually compile error or parsing error) raised up at `checkResource(Locale)` call, and in the following `renderMergedTemplateModel` call I will check if there are cached exception, if there is then render the exception screen, which is something like:

[image]

And yes, the developer friendly screen feature is only available when you set devMode to true (which is by default false) for `RythmConfigurer`:

```
<bean id="rythmConfig" class="org.rythmengine.spring.web.servlet.view.RythmConfigurer">
    <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/rythm/"/>
    <property name="outputRequestParameters" value="false"/>
    <property name="devMode" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: It looks like HandlerInterceptor cannot really handle the Exception. And I just found that the code do scan programatically doesn't work at all

Comment: Okey finally I end up with adding two annotations to another class. See the updates in the answer

Comment: In my case @EnableWebMvc was enough